# Detect File Change Without Polling

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a method within a Python program to detect whether a file on the file system has been modified.  I know that I could have something run on an every-5-seconds to check the last modification date off of the system, but I was curious as to whether there's an easier method for doing this, without needing to require my program to check repeatedly.

Does anyone know of such a method?

Comment: What platform?  Windows has a system service to register a callback when a directory or file changes.

Comment: Linux, but I'd prefer to make the program cross-platform compatible.

Comment: If you're programming for Windows you might consider the .Net File System Watcher. http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Watching_the_FileSystem

Comment: @TobiasKienzler it is so-so, this question wants to watch a *single* file.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For linux, there is [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki).

From the homepage:

> Pyinotify is a Python module for
>   monitoring filesystems changes.
>   Pyinotify relies on a Linux Kernel
>   feature (merged in kernel 2.6.13)
>   called inotify. inotify is an
>   event-driven notifier, its
>   notifications are exported from kernel
>   space to user space through three
>   system calls. pyinotify binds these
>   system calls and provides an
>   implementation on top of them offering
>   a generic and abstract way to
>   manipulate those functionalities.

Thus it is obviously not cross-platform and relies on a new enough kernel version. However, as far as I can see, requiring kernel support would be true about any non-polling mechanism.

Comment: Can pyinotify be used to detect the specific program that was used to modify a file?

Comment: Are the [objections against it](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2008/01/04/why-you-should-not-use-pyinotify/comment-page-1/) still valid?

Comment: this package exists no more

Comment: @AshokaLella: The package exists all right, but the project has moved from SF to github. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 83):

[watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/)

Excellent cross platform library for watching directories.

From the website

> **Supported Platforms**
>
> - Linux 2.6 (inotify)
> - Mac OS X (FSEvents, kqueue)
> - FreeBSD/BSD (kqueue)
> - Windows (ReadDirectoryChangesW with I/O completion ports; ReadDirectoryChangesW worker threads)
> - OS-independent (polling the disk for directory snapshots and comparing them periodically; slow and not recommended)

I've used it on a couple projects and it seems to work wonderfully.

Comment: The command-line tool is great for using in development.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: From the example given on the watchdog website, it looks like it requires polling.

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus: It does not. The example does `time.sleep(1)` to keep the example alive, but watchdog is actually asyncronous and will call event_handler in case of a file change event.

Comment: It seems that *watchdog* only works for directories. Is there a way to watch a non-directory file for changes without poling (using the kernels inotify)?

Answer (score 8):

On windows there is:

[watcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watcher), which is a nice python port of the .NET FileSystemWatcher API.

Also there's (the one I wrote) [dirwatch](https://bitbucket.org/otherchirps/dirwatch).

Both rely on the windows [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Though for real work, I'd use [watcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watcher) (proper C extension, good API, python 2 & 3 support).

Mine is mostly an experiment calling the relevant APIs on windows, so it's only interesting if you want an example of calling these things from python.

Comment: watcher seems to have been abandoned for a while and lacks proper documentation.

Comment: Yep, the scenery has changed since 2011...  Looks like watchdog is the best bet these days.

Answer (score 5):

You should also see [inotifyx](http://www.alittletooquiet.net/software/inotifyx/) which is very similar to the previously mentioned pyinotify, but is said to have an API which changes less.