# Watching for file changes within a directory

Tags: python, windows, linux, filesystems, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I watch a file for changes using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)
>   [Detect File Change Without Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738442/detect-file-change-without-polling)

I am trying to write an application which must perform an action when files are modified or added within a particular directory and its sub-directories.

I imagine that an ideal solution would be to bind to some type of system event that is fired by the operating system when a file or directory is modified. Another less-than-ideal solution would be for my application to manually, recursively check for file changes within a directory at a specified time interval, but this could get incredibly process-intensive if there are lots of files that must be checked every few minutes.

**Summary:** What is the best way for my application to watch for file changes within a directory?

For the scope of this question, assume that my application is written in Python and the operating system is Linux-based, but generalized answers that solve this problem for other languages and operating systems such as Windows or Mac OS are most welcome.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738442/detect-file-change-without-polling (there's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python for Windows). I've voted to close it as a duplicate of the first, I'd appreciate it if if you're voting to close it you make sure the second is also nominated... this can be a good signpost question. Watchdog is, in my opinion, the best answer, anyway. Great cross-platform support.

Comment: Chris, thanks for those links, they answer my question perfectly. I would vote to close, but I don't seem to have the privileges for that yet. This question can be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think libnotify is what you're looking for. You'll find it available for pretty much every language and OS. Here it is for [Python/Linux](http://shreyassiravara.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/using-libnotify-and-python/)

Answer (score 4):

As you have asked the question with Python Tag you may want to check [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/)