# Watchdog Python script for Windows file system

Tags: python, windows, watchdog

I would like to write a small notification script using python watchdog for windows. 
The script should do -  watch a directory and when ever file is created - trigger an exe passing filename as  argument.

This says for windows you need "lot of luck!!!" http://packages.python.org/watchdog/installation.html#installation-dependencies
How reliable or easy that would be ? Anyone tried such stuff with windows python ..any suggestions ?
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I watch a file for changes using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)

Comment: Also duplicate of: [Detect File Change Without Polling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738442/), [Watching for file changes within a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375588/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Comment: Have you checked for duplicates before answering this already answered question?