# Get only new lines from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-3.x

Currently i have this piece of code, but it reads all lines, and then watch the file with the while True statement:

```
with open('/var/log/logfile.log') as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print(line)
```

I actually only need new lines coming after the lines already detected when opening the file - anybody who can help me out? Maybe a better way to watch it aswell, than with the while statement?

Another problem is that on Linux machines the script is actually locking the file so it can not be written to, before i close the script again. On OS X it works fine. Could also be nice with an idea to work around this.

Hope there is somebody out there who have been working with something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could initially read the file completely, then close it, and keep a change monitor over it, this monitor is implemented below using polling.

```
import time

filePath = '/var/log/logfile.log'

lastLine = None
with open(filePath,'r') as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print(line)
            lastLine = line

while True:
    with open(filePath,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    if lines[-1] != lastLine:
        lastLine = lines[-1]
        print(lines[-1])
    time.sleep(1)
```

But you could also use tools like those described at: [Detect File Change Without Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738442/detect-file-change-without-polling)

Comment: This one is great, but still locking the file in Linux - any idea why?

Comment: @Adionditsak Try removing `with` sentence in the second loop, just: `f = open(...)` or getting out the lines from `if lines[-1]...` from the `with` block

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('/var/log/logfile.log','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Comment: Your last line `f.close()` is unnecessary since `f` will be closed at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo We need to close the file **f** explicitely otherwise troubles will occur depending on the nature and the scope of the application. I give you just a quick and short example: try to append data with more than one line (open file with `a` and write: yourfile.write("line 1") ... line 2 ... line 3. Don note type `yourfile.close()`. check your file with `cat yourfile.txt` (for example) and see if your lines are inserted or not.

Comment: As far as I understand, the resource opened within `with` will be closed at the end of its block. Answers like these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for seem to reinforce that idea. I have performed the test you suggested and I got the expected result, with all the lines inserted. Could you post an example where the situation you describe occurs?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo I followed the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) on the accepted answer of the question you showed to me. The official documentation says what you told me. I went back to a small script I did few days ago: I guessed that my problem had nothing to do with closing the file. I apologize for giving a wrong information. I updated my answer. Thank you very much for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
readfile = open('/var/log/logfile.log','r')
if readfile:
   for lines in readfile:
      print lines
readfile.close()
```