# Python logging: change configuration without restart?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python logging module and using YAML file to define the configuration, then initialize the logging as follows:

```
with open(config_file_path, 'r') as f:
        config = yaml.load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Is there a way to monitor for file changes so that the new configuration is automatically picked up by logging module without having to restart the application?

Comment: Seems your question is not about python logging at all but about detecting file changes, many duplicates for that. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738442/detect-file-change-without-polling
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python
etc.

Comment: Thanks @Eran for the link!

Answer (score 1):

You can set your logger to [listen for config changes on a socket](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#configuration-server-example).