# How to get the diff of a file asynchronously in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, checksum

I'm writing a component of a web app that displays the `tail` of a log file.

My current attempt is to use web sockets to emit the changes in the file, ensure that I have fewer than `n` lines, and tack it into a text area.

My current problem is how to generate `'on change'` events for the log file in Python.

I could conceivably detect changes of `some_log.log` by creating a copy `some_copy.log` with [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html), detect the last time the file was changed with [`os.path.getmtime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime), take the diff and emit the changes. This reeks of inefficiency.

Does anyone have suggestions for asynchronously detecting changes in files using Python? I'm using Python 2.7.6.

Comment: I think this question has already been asked : [detect-file-change-without-polling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738442/detect-file-change-without-polling)

Comment: @Benjamin Most of those tools are dir-watchers as opposed to file-watchers. Further, most of them have been abandoned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to add this for future readers, but if others want to suggest alternative ideas, I'll happily entertain them.

I found a package called [tailer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tailer) which is a wrapper around the unix tail program. Roughly in pythonic pseudocode, I plan to do the following in a separate thread:

```
for line in tailer.follow(open('some_log.log')):
    emit(line)
```